# Sharepoint 2013 - Error XSL List error with user not Logged in

Tags: 2013, xslt, boot-strap

This is my first topic so I apologize if something is not in order and I apologize for my bad english.

I have a problem with a particular SP13 list.

I created an XSL that uses JQUERY and BOOTSTRAP to format some lists.

XSL is working normally and formatting as there was project in a list.

While in another list it only works when the user is logged in, when the user is not logged in it misconfigures the entire list.

The strange thing is that in the first list it works normally even with the logged off user.

I have already compared the lists and I can not find the BUG.

Any idea what that might be?

Comment: is  the two list in the same site and use the same customization and the same css / jquery file ?

Comment: In fact my structure would be divided by list.

I end up replicating the files by list type because I change some formatting classes in each type. Change of color, size, etc.

But I do not change anything in JQUERY that has the function to make the accordion work.

Example:

List 1
--CSS
--XSL
--JS

List 2
--CSS
--XSL
--JS

Comment: try to publish the modified css file related to list 2 as a major version

Answer (score 0):

I think you have modified some files related to the second list that not `published as a Major version`

So Try to save and check in your files then publish it as a major version as shown below

[image]

Now the visitors' users should see the customization of list 2

Comment: Thanks for the help bro I had really forgotten something. But now I have another problem.

The native Modal is not opening. Uncaught TypeError: Can not read property 'hiddenButtonValueBeforeDialog' of undefined (...)

I do not know what it can be.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 
    function dialogfunction(pageUrl) {
var options = { url: pageUrl, width: 800, height: 600 };
SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
}   
   </script>
   
<a class="produto-item" href='javascript:dialogfunction("/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=4&amp;ListId=%7BDDBCA2F6%2D0FD1%2D4472%2D9CC8%2D1BC8BFDF3C41%7D&amp;ID={@ID}")' onmouseover="javascript:this.style.cursor='pointer';">
          

          </a>

Comment: you are welcome :) are you forget the publish of major version or something else ?! for the another issue should you elaborate more to can help you faster

Comment: where's hiddenButtonValueBeforeDialog in your posted code ? i can't find it

Comment: So this time I'm posting the biggest version. On the other case it happens that I need to open the list item in the form of a modal. And for this I am using the Sharepoint native. But it happens that you are giving the error Uncaught TypeError: Can not read property 'hiddenButtonValueBeforeDialog' of undefined (...) or similar by changing function only.


[link](http://i64.tinypic.com/25sy73o.png)

Comment: this mean you tried to call a function that is not defined in your code, my suggestion is to open a new question with the detail code and description  to allow more people help you with me also check this http://www.mysharepointadventures.com/2012/04/content-query-webpart-and-data-view-webpart-modal-dialogs/ may help you

Comment: Regarding first issue that you have asked in this question , if my answer is helped you please set it as answer,  it's the true sign beside my answer , as mentioned at http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour also to gain informed badge !

Comment: thank you for your help bro...
I tried the idea of the link you sent, but it did not work.
You're making the same mistake yet.
I do not know why it does not work, I mirrored the idea of opening via modal of another page that I have working but in this it does not work.
I read in some article that asks to declare the script below, but when I add the line it gives error.
<Script type = "text / javascript" src = "/ _ layouts / 15 / ScriptResx.ashx? Name = sp.res & culture = en-us"> </ script>